# Where is this quote about Man, Hero, Legend and Myth from?

Tags: quote-source

This quote is scattered throughout the Web:

> Through action, a Man becomes a Hero
>
> Through death, a Hero becomes a Legend
>
> Through time, a Legend becomes a Myth
>
> And by learning from the Myth, a Man takes action

I've seen it attributed to [Eiichiro Oda](https://platinumscars.deviantart.com/journal/Epic-Quote-from-One-Piece-580479115), [Joseph Campbell](https://www.facebook.com/blackknightpage/posts/333736176746040?comment_id=916799645106354&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R0%22%7D), and many others. Where is it originally from?

Comment: If Joseph Campbell originally said it, It was quite likely translated into Japanese and then back into English, and came out unrecognizable.

Answer (score -1):

The quote is an original writing from Oda himself, but it definitely echoes the message from Joseph Campbell's works.

Comment: Do you have any source/evidence for the statement that this quote is due to Oda?

Comment: @Randal'Thor: would a screenshot of the anime authored by Eiichiro Oda count as a source/evidence?
https://www.mai-on.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/hero.png (from the article https://www.mai-on.com/best-anime-quotes/)

Comment: @Jeremy: Ideally we would like to know a bit more detail, since a screenshot has low evidential value (anyone can add text to a screenshot). A good reference would include (i) the name of the anime; (ii) the speaker and timestamp of the line; (iii) the original Japanese dialogue; (iv) some details of the translation into English. But if the line comes originally from the manga, then a page reference to the manga would be even better.